# TextView setText("1x") doesn't work

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView on my Activity layout. If i setText("1x") the "x" isnt shown on Android 2.x devices. But if i execute setText("1xx") the TextView is set with "1x". Has anyone a tip?

Comment: can you please post your code ?

Comment: Looks like a layout issue to me. I don't think it has to do anything with the character 'x'. Its just your text at the end which is getting clipped/hidden.

Comment: @NiteshGarg youre right. Sorry for that stupid question